# Java WebApp keeps returning same results

Tags: java, json, servlets

I wrote this web application that after inputing coordinates of a city (latitude, longitude) (source: [json](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson)) returns the list of 10 closest earthquakes that happened in the US. Now, I have 2 problems:

**Problem 1.**

1. I enter coordinates of a chosen city (e.g. Seattle) and I get the proper results.
2. I enter coordinates of the second city (e.g. Washington D.C.), I get different (proper) results.
3. I enter the same coordinates od the first city (e.g. Seattle) and the results are the same as with the previous second search.
4. I enter the coordinates of third, fourth, sixth etc. city and I keep getting the same results.

It's like the application was being stuck (after 2-3 proper queries?). Sometimes I get three different results in a row, sometimes four, sometimes just two and later same results are being printed. If I hardcode the coordinates into Servlet into the Java method, the results are different each time, so I'm guessing there is some problem passing the input fields into the Java method.
It doesn't matter if I chose from the list the city or I type in coordinates myself.

**Problem 2.**

1. I choose a city from the dropdown list.
2. Coordinates are being input into the input html form, e.g. Kansas City: Latitude: 39.099728 Longitude -94.578568.
3. I add letters/signs to the latitude e.g. **39.099728sdjfhjsdf**, longitude: -94.578568 **and I press submit**.
4. I get info that the field is not formatted properly (that's OK until now).
5. I chose from a dropdown list another city, the input fields are being filled with new coordinates and I press submit, **but I keep getting the warning the number is not formatted properly** (like the program even though the input is new would be still reading **39.099728sdjfhjsdf**).

Here is the minimal working example. Project wrote in Eclipse.

ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.dominikazb.earthquakes.engine.ReadJsonFile;

@WebServlet("/read")
public class ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String latitudeOfSearchedCityString = request.getParameter("latitudeOfSearchedCity");
    String longitudeOfSearchedCityString = request.getParameter("longitudeOfSearchedCity");
    ReadJsonFile.getReadJson().convertJsonToJavaObjects(latitudeOfSearchedCityString, longitudeOfSearchedCityString);
    response.sendRedirect("list");
}
}
```

PrintEarthquakesServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.dominikazb.earthquakes.engine.ReadJsonFile;

@WebServlet("/list")
public class PrintEarthquakesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    TreeMap<Double, String> outputMap = ReadJsonFile.getReadJson().read10closestCities();
    request.setAttribute("outputMap", outputMap);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/earthquakesList.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

ReadJsonFile.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ReadJsonFile {

    private static ReadJsonFile readJson = new ReadJsonFile();  
    private static String place;
    private static double longitude;
    private static double latitude; 
    private Map<Double, String> distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities = new TreeMap<>();
    private HarvesineFormula harvesine = new HarvesineFormula();

public static ReadJsonFile getReadJson() {
    return readJson;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void convertJsonToJavaObjects(String latitudeOfSearchedCity, String longitudeOfSearchedCity) throws IOException, JsonParseException {

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();               
    om.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); //ignore fields that are not formatted properly
    TypeReference<HashMap<Object,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<Object,Object>>() {};
    HashMap<Object, Object> resultMap = om.readValue(new URL("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson"), typeRef);

    ArrayList<Object> featuresArrayList = (ArrayList<Object>) resultMap.get("features");

    for(Object o : featuresArrayList) {
        try {
            LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> featuresLinkedHashMapInside = (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>) o;
            Map<Object, Object> newMapping = (Map<Object, Object>) featuresLinkedHashMapInside.get("properties");
            place = newMapping.get("place").toString();
            Map<Object, Object> geometryMap = (Map<Object, Object>) featuresLinkedHashMapInside.get("geometry");
            ArrayList<Object> coordinatesArrayList = (ArrayList<Object>) geometryMap.get("coordinates");            
            longitude = (double) coordinatesArrayList.get(0);
            latitude = (double) coordinatesArrayList.get(1);

            double latitudeOfSearchedCityDouble = Double.parseDouble(latitudeOfSearchedCity);
            double longitudeOfSearchedCityDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitudeOfSearchedCity);

            double distanceBetweenTheCityAndEarthquakes = 
                    harvesine.haversine(latitudeOfSearchedCityDouble, longitudeOfSearchedCityDouble, latitude, longitude);

            distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities.put(distanceBetweenTheCityAndEarthquakes, place);


        } catch (ClassCastException | NullPointerException e) {
            continue;
        }
    }           
}

public TreeMap<Double, String> read10closestCities() {
    TreeMap<Double, String> first10resultsFromTheList = distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities.entrySet().stream()
            .limit(10)
            .collect(TreeMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), Map::putAll);  
    return first10resultsFromTheList;
}
}
```

HarvesineFormula.java

```
public class HarvesineFormula {

public double haversine(double latitude1stCity, double longitude1stCity, 
        double latitude2ndCity, double longitude2ndCity) {

    double distanceBetweenLatitudes = Math.toRadians(latitude2ndCity - latitude1stCity);
    double distanceBetweenLongitudes = Math.toRadians(longitude2ndCity - longitude1stCity);
    latitude1stCity = Math.toRadians(latitude1stCity);
    latitude2ndCity = Math.toRadians(latitude2ndCity);
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(distanceBetweenLatitudes / 2), 2) + 
            Math.pow(Math.sin(distanceBetweenLongitudes / 2), 2) * 
            Math.cos(latitude1stCity) * Math.cos(latitude2ndCity);
    double radiusOfTheEarth = 6371;
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return radiusOfTheEarth * c;
}
}
```

earthquakesList.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


        <div>
            <form action="/read" method="post">
                <label>Latitude</label> 
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" 
                    name="latitudeOfSearchedCity" 
                    id="latitudeOfSearchedCity" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Type in latitude in a format 00.000')"
                    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
                    oninput="setCustomValidity(' ')"
                    pattern="^[-]?(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$"
                    required="required" />
                </fieldset>

                <label>Longitude</label> 
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" 
                    name="longitudeOfSearchedCity" 
                    id="longitudeOfSearchedCity" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Type in longitude in a format 00.000')"
                    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"
                    oninput="setCustomValidity(' ')"            
                    pattern="^[-]?(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$" 
                    required="required" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                <label>Select a city</label> 
                <select id="countrySelect">
                    <option>None</option>
                    <option value="35.084385_-106.650421">Albuquerque</option>                              
                    <option value="33.748997_-84.387985">Atlanta</option>
                    <option value="41.878113_-87.629799">Chicago</option>                           
                    <option value="32.776665_-96.796989">Dallas</option>
                    <option value="39.739235_-104.990250">Denver</option>   
                    <option value="31.761877_-106.485023">El Paso</option>                                                          
                    <option value="29.760427_-95.369804">Houston</option>                                                       
                    <option value="30.332184_-81.655647">Jacksonville</option>
                    <option value="39.099728_-94.578568">Kansas City</option>   
                    <option value="36.169941_-115.139832">Las Vegas</option>                                
                    <option value="34.052235_-118.243683">Los Angeles</option>                                                      
                    <option value="35.149532_-90.048981">Memphis</option>   
                    <option value="43.038902_-87.906471">Milwaukee</option>         
                    <option value="44.977753_-93.265015">Minneapolis</option>                                                       
                    <option value="29.951065_-90.071533">New Orleans</option>                                                                                   
                    <option value="40.712776_-74.005974">New York City</option>
                    <option value="28.538336_-81.379234">Orlando</option>                       
                    <option value="39.952583_-75.165222">Philadelphia</option>
                    <option value="33.448376_-112.074036">Phoenix</option>                              
                    <option value="40.440624_-79.995888">Pittsburgh</option>
                    <option value="45.512230_-122.658722">Portland</option>                                 
                    <option value="38.581573_-121.494400">Sacramento</option>                                   
                    <option value="29.424122_-98.493629">San Antonio</option>   
                    <option value="32.715736_-117.161087">San Diego</option>                                        
                    <option value="37.338207_-121.886330">San Jose</option>                                                                                                 
                    <option value="47.606209_-122.33206">Seattle</option>
                    <option value="38.627003_-90.199402">St. Louis</option> 
                    <option value="32.222607_-110.974709">Tucson</option>                           
                    <option value="38.907192_-77.036873">Washington D.C.</option>                                                                                           
                </select>
                </fieldset>

                <br />

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="resultsTable2">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                        <th>Location</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${outputMap}" var="entry">
                        <tr>
                            <td><fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="1"
                                    value="${entry.key}" /> KM</td>
                            <td><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#countrySelect').on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var parts = val.split("_");
    $('#latitudeOfSearchedCity').val(parts[0]);
    $('#longitudeOfSearchedCity').val(parts[1]);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PrintEarthquakesServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.dominikazb.earthquakes.servlets.PrintEarthquakesServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.dominikazb.earthquakes.servlets.ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PrintEarthquakesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PrintEarthquakesServlet</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ReadLongitudeAndLatitudeServlet</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>earthquakesList.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dominikazb</groupId>
<artifactId>10closestEarthquakes</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>10closestEarthquakes Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.50</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jsimone/webapp-runner -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.27.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>10closestEarthquakes</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>todo</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}
                </webappDirectory>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.27.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/dominikazb/10closestEarthquakes). Please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main logical error is here:

```
distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities.put(distanceBetweenTheCityAndEarthquakes, place);
```

because that map grows forever.

Add this line to your method

```
distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities = new TreeMap<>();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();           
...
```

and you get the correct answers, because for each call of the method you "reset" the map.

Anyway I see some other "wrong ideas" in your code like

- use of static fields that seems to be not very useful
- share "place" between 2 different function calls (in a multi-thread environment you can get into problems)

Anyway I hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks! Resetting does help indeed! Do you have any suggestions how to omit creating of this map that grows forever? In order to sort distances by their size I have to go through all of the results (a map seemed the easiest way). Sorry for the static fields, it's the leftover of the previous version, I have deleted them as I do not use them. Thanks for all the comments, they are very useful!

Comment: Have you seen this page?
[link]https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/)(https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/)
There is a "query" method to invoke (with many query parameters) and it seems to me that the response has the same form of your current call to all_month.geojson

Comment: Sorry for the error in  [link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/)
it gets you to "API Documentation - Earthquake Catalog"

Comment: No, I haven't seen this page, thanks I will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, there are  a few problems with the ReadJson class and how it is used.

1. ReadJson is used as a Singleton, i.e. there will be only one instance of this class and it will be shared among all HTTP requests.
2. Each new HTTP request will populate the `distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities` member of the ReadJson class. Note that this member will contain data for all previous requests. It is also a TreeMap sorted on the distance, so it is not strange that after a while you get the same results.
3. Each HTTP request will fetch the json data file over the network and parse it.

You should refactor the handling of the JSON data. Read the JSON file only once (or once a day to pick up updates). When computing the `distanceAndPlaceMapForAllCities`, make sure to use a new instance for each request.

Comment: Thanks, those are very useful comments of things I have not noticed before! Thanks, I will apply them all! :)